# Adding a bg-image at top for active link in <li>, possible?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-image

I am trying to add small arrow type image above the link which is active. I tried a few basic things, but I am not getting the image at all. Probably I am doing something wrong, or it's not possible...?

This is what I am trying to make it look like:

[image: example of what I am trying to achieve]

Current html:

```
<li><li class="currentlink"><a href="nieuws.php" target="_parent">nieuws</a></li>
<li><a href="behandelingen.php" target="_parent">behandelingen</a></li>
<li><a href="producten.php" target="_parent">producten</a></li>
```

Current CSS:

```
.currentlink{background-image:url(images/naviarrow.png) no-repeat;width:25px;height:14px;}
```

What am I doing wrong here...? Can someone explain or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is that a direct copy/paste of your code?  You have a stray opening `li` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to place the image with 'width' and 'height'. You can declare the styles 'top' and 'center' which will place your image exactly there.

For example:

```
.currentlink { background: #000 url(images/naviarrow.png) no-repeat top center }
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kEaVb/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I was out with a cold. After seeing your example I managed to make it work (with a couple of changes). Thank you for your help. Highly appreciated.